# Variance in bytes sent while using Fprintf

Tags: go

Requirement: I would like to get "4 bytes sent" - when i send the following hex message - i see them working for one hex message and does not work for the other one when sent with a minor change

The following code explains my problem better - first the working hex with 4 bytes sent as expected and second with another hex message which sends additional bytes - i need to figure out a way to get 4 bytes sent for the second hex too

### Working hex:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    hexString, _ := hex.DecodeString("4214722e")

    n, err := fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, string(hexString))

    // The n and err return values from Fprintf are
    // those returned by the underlying io.Writer.
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fprintf: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n%d bytes written.\n", n)
    fmt.Println([]byte(hexString))
    fmt.Println(hex.Dump(hexString))

}
```

Produces the following as output:

```
4 bytes written.
[66 20 114 46]
00000000  42 14 72 2e                                       |B.r.|
```

### Not working hex - with just one value changed: (Need 4 bytes here somehow but i get 13)

https://play.golang.org/p/UNLsLdLk6g0

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    hexString, _ := hex.DecodeString("42147225")

    n, err := fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, string(hexString))

    // The n and err return values from Fprintf are
    // those returned by the underlying io.Writer.
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fprintf: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n%d bytes written.\n", n)
    fmt.Println([]byte(hexString))
    fmt.Println(hex.Dump(hexString))

}
```

Produces the following output which is not what is expected, even if the bytes when printed looks to be 4

```
13 bytes written.
[66 20 114 37]
00000000  42 14 72 25                                       |B.r%|
```

Need 4 bytes to be sent in the second example - please help me out with the same

Note: Why am i using Fprintf here? I need this message to be sent via a TCP socket, but for the example above - i am sending the same hex message but to the stdout instead so that its easy for us to take a look at this. As long as the solution can be used for sending info to sockets - i dont really care if its Fprintf or something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the printed string, you can see the problem:

```
Br%!(NOVERB)
```

Here, when the last byte is 0x25, which is '%', Fprintf tries to read the next formatting verb from the input, which is not there, so it prints out an error message !(NOVERB). That's your extra bytes. Instead of Fprintf, use FPrint, and it should print 4 bytes.